# current user.is_authenticated gives me a True value but it didn't work in base.html file

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in or not to change nav elements and to do more stuff and here is my code

And when I do this

`print(attempted_account.is_authenticated)` result => `True`

I think that the problem will be in `base.html` file so I hope you can help me.

**routs.py:**

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        attempted_account = Account.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        print(attempted_account.is_authenticated)
        if attempted_account and attempted_account.check_password(attempted_password=form.password.data):
            login_user(attempted_account)
            flash('Success login ',category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('page',id=1))
        elif not attempted_account:
            flash("The E-mail doesn't exist",category='danger')
        else:
            flash('Tha password is incorrect',category='danger')
    return render_template('login.html',form=form)
```

**base.html**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="home" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Market</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('page',id=1) }}">Go shopping</a></li> 
    </ul>
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li> 
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('signup') }}">Sign up</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a></li> 
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</nav>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Login
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" class="form-register" style="text-align: center;">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}

    {{ form.email.label() }}
    {{ form.email(class='form-control',placeholder='example@example.com') }}
    <br>
    {{ form.password.label() }}
    {{ form.password(class='form-control',placeholder='Password') }}
    <br>
    {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary') }}
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

***Please note that I called my model Account not User***

**Edit:**

Here is models.py:

```
from market import db
from market import bcrypt,login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Account.query.filter_by(id=user_id)

class Account(db.Model,UserMixin):

id              = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key = True)
first_name      = db.Column(db.String(length = 50),nullable  = False)
last_name       = db.Column(db.String(length = 50),nullable  =False)
email           = db.Column(db.String(length = 100),nullable =False,unique = True)
password_hashed = db.Column(db.String(length = 25),nullable = False)
#country        = db.Column(db.String,nullable = False)
items           = db.relationship('Item',backref = 'owner',lazy = True)

@property
def password(self):
    return self.password
@password.setter
def password(self,plain_text_password):
    self.password_hashed = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plain_text_password).decode('utf-8')
def check_password(self,attempted_password):
    return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password_hashed,attempted_password)
```

Comment: Have you defined a `user_loader` callback as described in the documentation? https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works

Comment: Yes I imported UserMixin

Comment: Can you add the `user_loader` callback and `Account` implementation for us to take a look? Also, after submitting the login form, is the user correctly redirected?

Comment: I edited the question , and the User is redirected correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably because you're returning a query result in the `user_loader` callback instead of an `Account` object.

Instead of returning `Account.query.filter_by(id=user_id)` try returning `Account.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()`.

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you alot .... I took the whole day to solve this